# Rails 4 .each printing an extra empty result

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a comments table for a link and the form looks like this:

```
<%= form_for([@link, @link.item_comments.build]) do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, value: current_user.id %>
  <%= f.text_area :content %>
  <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
<% end %>
```

I'm printing comments out to the page with:

```
<ul>
    <% @link.item_comments.each do |comment| %>
      <li><%= comment.content %> <%= comment.user_name %></li>
      Points: <%= comment.points %>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
```

But when I view the page I'm getting an extra, empty element printed out at the end. Can anyone explain what's going on? I think it might be something to do with the `.build` in the form, but I can't find anything about it.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that `.build` is the cause.

From the [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many):

> **collection.build(attributes = {}, …)** Returns one or more new objects of the collection type that have been instantiated with attributes and linked to this object through a foreign key, but have not yet been saved.

but even though it hasn't been saved yet it will be added so that it appears in the `@link.item_comments` collection that you're using for your `each` loop.

From the rest of your code it looks like you must be associated the comment with the link when the comment gets saved anyway and you can just use `form_for([@link, ItemComment.new])` for the `form_for`.

Comment: "even though it hasn't been saved yet it will be added so that it appears..."
Yep. What actually solved it in my case is simply putting the form above the loop in the view. Thanks